# Reading constant number of characters in C++

Tags: c++, string, spaces, istream

How would you read a string if it was no longer than 20 characters and could contain spaces in C++? For example I have this kind of file:

```
3
Namama               4 5 12
Cool                 4 2 34
Not So Cool          4 2 45
```

I want to write it in the most basic way possible. And I would prefer using only C++ (no C thingies) in this case. This means I want to store it in std::string.

I could use *istream::get* or *istream::getline* but then I have to avoid the new line characters. This is problematic (and the code I'm writing is going to be shown to beginners).

What are your solutions for this problem?

**Edit:**

As asked I'm going to tell you what I have tried but I don't think it's going to be any good. I am not a C++ beginner and usually I would have used something like *istream::get* and char array but removing new line characters might seem too techy for some people.

So... Either reading char array or *std::string* using *istream::operator>>* fails because it stops reading when they see space character (and I may have to read several words). This means the following code fails:

```
char name[21];
std::cin >> name;
```

or...

```
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
```

Another thing is that new line characters differ from system to system and actually Windows use two of them by default and I have tried using *istream::ignore* with 2 as an argument on Windows and that was the only way to ignore the new line and I came to conclusion that it's because Windows use two characters for a new line mark. That means it wouldn't work on Linux and it would have to be more complex... Again - bad for beginners.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the code you have so far so people can help fixing/improving specific parts of it.

Comment: "new line characters differ from system to system" - the fix for that is to open the file in character mode instead of binary mode. Then whatever the local newline sequence is, it's translated to `\n` on read.

Comment: Do you only want the initial string, or do you want to parse the entire line, including the numbers? If you want the latter, I'd go for a holistic approach.

Comment: "new line characters differ from system to system" -- perhaps they do while they are stored on disk, but they do not differ in your C++ program. `'\n'` **always** represents the end of a line, and nothing else does.

Comment: @SteveJessop and Rob there are two kinds of istream functions - formatted and unformatted. Their behaviour differs.

Comment: @Valdo: `istream::ignore(1000, '\n');` should work on any OS

Comment: @Valdo: there are, but the difference between text and binary mode is completely independent of the difference between formatted and unformatted operations on streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read *exactly* 20 characters,

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    std::string result;
    int one, two, three;

    result.resize(20);
    if (!std::cin.read(&result[0], 20)) throw std::runtime_error("reading buffer failed!");

    if (!std::cin >> one >> two >> three) throw std::runtime_error("reading numbers failed!");
    if (!std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n')) throw std::runtime_error("ignore failed!");
}
```

If you don't want exactly 20 characters, how do you know when you've reached the end of the string?

Comment: haven't used iostream::read but the reference says that it's an unformatted input function and doesn't it mean that it is going to read the new line character left after the last reading? I still would have to use istream::ignore. Anyways, will try in a few minutes

Comment: @Valdo: I fixed it to read in 20 again, got confused with `.get()` for a moment.  This will leave whatever is after the 20 characters, including a newline.

Comment: but it read new line as well. actually it causes some very weird behavior I don't understand but trying to figure it out. I have always thought that this function is for binary reading only (remembered using it) but apparently not.

Comment: @Valdo: It should read exactly 20 bytes, including spaces and newlines.  What's the wierd behavior?

Comment: @Mooning Duck Well, it causes errors when reading the input. after it reads the first line, it fails to read the following lines... trying to figure out what is wrong now...

Comment: @Valdo: I added exceptions.  That may or may not help.

Comment: Ok... Going to mark this one as an answer because it doesn't seem anyone has a suggestion that works without using istream::ignore. Too bad. it seems sad that you can't read string with spaces without getting into unformatted input.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to use istream::read into a temporary buffer of sufficient size, and then use that buffer to initialize a std::string.

```
char name[21];
std::cin.read(name, 20);
std::string nameString(name); // If you want it in a std::string
```

This reads exactly 20 characters, newlines and everything. If it's for an exercise, then this is at the very least very simple. If you sometimes want less than 20 characters, it is possible to determine how many extra were read and back the get pointer by std::istream::unget or equivalent.